# Mysql no longer working and cannot reinstall

Tags: mysql, linux

I am on ubuntu 16.04 and my mysql connection to local database suddenly stopped working one day, I then tried various things to fix it, but then came to trying to completely remove and reinstall it but when I do it errors out

Systemctl status mysql.service

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-01-07 10:26:11 GMT; 15s ago
  Process: 14346 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 14339 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14346 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 14347 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─14347 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─14403 sleep 1
```

Journalctl -xe

```
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 audit[14346]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14346/status" pid=14346 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 audit[14346]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=14346 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 audit[14346]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14346/status" pid=14346 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546856771.110:25227): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14346/status" pid=14346 comm="mysqld" reque
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546856771.110:25228): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=14346 comm="mysqld
Jan 07 10:26:11 np161-Vostro-3268 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546856771.110:25229): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/14346/status" pid=14346 comm="mysqld" reque
Jan 07 10:26:13 np161-Vostro-3268 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 07 10:26:14 np161-Vostro-3268 sudo[13239]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 07 10:26:42 np161-Vostro-3268 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Just dumping a stack trace with little explanation isn't likely to get any help here.  You might want to also tell us what you have tried to remedy the situation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried to clear up disk space and also tried chown chmod to allow permissions and then tried a full removal and reinstall but it keeps failing when trying to install mysql-server.

Comment: Have you tried to `purge` everything related to `mysql` and then reinstall?

Comment: @MichaelO. I followed the list of commands here https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apparmor seems to be stopping you.